# phonegap sqlite no such table found

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am working on Phonegap in Eclipse IDE to develop an Android app using sqlite as my database. 
In my index.html I'm creating the database using db.openDatabase. In the file explorer under data>data>com.app>app_storage> a database is created 00001.db
In the same page I'm creating my tables (7 in total) and populating one of them.
As I navigate to a different page and try to query the tables I get an error in logCat saying "no such table"
Why does this happen ? How do I fix this ?

I see SQLiteLog no such table cdpportal_employee_details

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
     <head>



    <title>Embedded Sql Example</title>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        var db;
        var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
        var maxSize = 65535;
        role="false";

        function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
           alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);
        }


        function successCallBack() {
           alert("DEBUGGING: success");
        }

        function nullHandler(){alert ("TABLE CREATED");}


        function onBodyLoad(){


            alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");

            if (!window.openDatabase) {

                alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
                return;
            }


            db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);

            db.transaction(function(tx){

            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdpportal_employee_details(employee_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,password TEXT,role TEXT,employee_name TEXT,contact_number NUMBER,email_id TEXT)');
            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdpportal_course_details(course_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,course_name TEXT NOT NULL,start_date TEXT NOT NULL,end_date TEXT NOT NULL,sess TEXT,instructor_name TEXT,techassociate_name TEXT,venue TEXT)');
            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdpportal_attendance_code_gen(course_id TEXT,day TEXT,attendance_code TEXT,FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_course_details(course_id),PRIMARY KEY (course_id,day,attendance_code) )');
            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdpportal_registered_emp(employee_id TEXT ,course_id TEXT ,FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_employee_details(employee_id),FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_course_details(course_id),PRIMARY KEY(employee_id, course_id))');
            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdpportal_removed_courses(admin_id TEXT,course_id TEXT,course_name TEXT,FOREIGN KEY (admin_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_employee_details(employee_id),FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_course_details(course_id),PRIMARY KEY (admin_id, course_id))');
            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdpportal_attendance_record(employee_id TEXT,course_id TEXT,day TEXT,attended TEXT,FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_employee_details(employee_id),FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_course_details(course_id),PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, course_id))');
            tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cdpportal_assesment_result(employee_id TEXT,course_id TEXT ,handson_marks NUMBER,objective_marks NUMBER,FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_employee_details(employee_id),FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES cdpportal_course_details(course_id),PRIMARY KEY(course_id,employee_id))');
            tx.executeSql('insert into cdpportal_emploee_details values ("rifath","Qwerty","E","Sri Harsha L",9633852741,"sriharsha@infosys.com")');
            },nullHandler,successCallBack);


        }
function fun()
{

var uname=document.getElementById("usrnm").value;
var pwd=document.getElementById("pswd").value;
db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql( 'SELECT role from cdpportal_employee_details where employee_id=? AND        password=?',[uname, pwd], function(tx, results)
    {
        role=results.value;

    }, null);
});
alert(role);

}


    </script>
</head>


<body onload="onBodyLoad()">

    <h1>WebSQL</h1>
    <form>
  <div>
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <label for="usrnm" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="usrnm" placeholder="Username">
      <label for="pswd" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="passw" id="pswd" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Log in" onclick= fun() style="color : teal; background-color: #FFFFC0"> 
    </div>
 </form>

</body>
```

(1) no such table: cdpportal_emploee_details

Comment: I googled for a sample code for using sqlite with phonegap and came across numerous examples that state that they are using sqlite. How do I use the sqlite plugin ? A step by step approach would be appreciated

Comment: sorry I just noticed a spelling error but now it throws (23) not authorized

Comment: I am using eclipse Build: v21.0.1-543035. Please help I have almost given up hope

Comment: See my edited answer, I believe a simple typo is the cause of your problem

Answer (score 0):

before proceeding with your question are you sure that you are using `sqlite database` please refer to phonegap documentation

```
This API is based on the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C Web Storage API Specification. Some devices already provide an implementation of this spec. For those devices, the built-in support is used instead of replacing it with PhoneGap's implementation. For devices that don't have storage support, PhoneGap's implementation should be compatible with the W3C specification.
```

More details [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Database)

AFAIK for sqlite you need to use a plugin but websql is something that phonegap supports natively, so, as per my understanding you are using web-sql not sqlite

Now, coming to your question I am not sure you are facing the problem that I once faced, this may be wrong but still, I faced the same problem actually the database that was created was like `saldi.db.db` and I was looking for `saldi.db` this actually created a new database, so you may try clearing this database/ un installing app and then check for this file before firing any query to save or fetch data from table just make sure that correct database is created

cheers

Comment: did you try this suggestion?

Comment: I did try to install the plugin. But in SQLitePlugin.java there shows a compilation error saying the min version is 8 and required is 17. I am interning in an institution that can provide me version 8 at the best. 
Could you provide any links for a tutorial on how to use the plugin ? Please keep in mind I am a newbie and am using Eclipse Classic IDE

Comment: you do not need sqlite plugin here, you may well do with web-sql,you can have a look at code here https://gist.github.com/liamartinez/3791512 and if this helps you may consider upvoting/accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to that page, you have to make sure the table exists.  So look at where you have done your CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS statement.

For example if the create statement is inside a function, check if that function has been called on that specific page.

EDIT:  I have found your problem:

```
tx.executeSql('insert into cdpportal_emploee_details values ("rifath","Qwerty","E","Sri Harsha L",9633852741,"sriharsha@infosys.com")');
```

you are missing the "y" in cdpportal_emploee_details

Answer (score 0):

I have only just begin my struggle with jQuery, Cordova/PhoneGap, and SQLite, but one possibility might be that you are running into a race condition. The SQLite plugin operates asynchronously in the background, so your page might be loading before those transactions are complete. Try inserting your `openDatabase` call in a promise, so that you use it only after you're sure it's created.

```
function initDB()
{
    var promLoaded = $.Deferred() ; // creates a promise

    db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(/* your DB params; should be JSON obj for plugin */) ;
    db.transaction(
        function(tx) // initial transaction request
        { tx.executeSql(/* your CREATE TABLE statement */) ; }
        ,
        function(err) // error callback
        { console.log(err) ; } 
        ,
        function(tx,rs) // success callback
        { // chain a pre-population query off the success of the table creation
            db.transaction(
                function(tx)
                { tx.executeSql(/* INSERT statement to pre-populate data*/ ) ; }
                ,
                function(err)
                { console.log(err) ; }
                ,
                function(tx,rs)
                {
                    console.log( "Tables ready." ) ;
                    promLoaded.resolve() ; // promise resolves when stuff is complete
                }
            );
        }
    );

    return promLoaded.promise() ; // return the promise to the caller
}
```

Using this scheme you should be able to start using the table as soon as `initDB().done()` has executed.

If you pass this promise around then you can check on its status later and wait on your `SELECT` until you know the promise has been resolved.

I have only just started learning this myself, gotten this to happen properly in my own app, and have barely begun testing it, so I hope there are no grievous errors in the above. YMMV.